# How do I avoid code duplication in this example?

Tags: c++

I have a simple library (let's call it `Library #1`) that manipulates some data vector (e.g. a time series). I want to make a new library (`Library #2`) which has essentially most (but not all) of the same functions, but acts on only a single data point in that vector. I imagine a solution that is a thin wrapper of the existing library one, that minimizes code duplication.

Here is the simple `Library #1`:

```
class Foo {
private: 
   std::vector<double> data;

public:
   // Some constructors

   double get_data_at_timepoint(int timepoint) const;

   // Some other methods
}
```

`get_data_at_timepoint` just returns the appropriate element of the data vector (assuming it exists). The other class in the library `Bar` has a container of `Foo` and manipulates them in some way - in particular, it can `do_something`, and you can also get a `Foo`:

```
class Bar {
private:
    std::vector<Foo> foos;

public:
    // Some constructors

    Foo get_this_foo(int idx) const;

    void do_something();

    // Some other methods
}
```

where (**important**) `do_something` calls `get_data_at_timepoint` in some way:

```
void Bar::do_something() {
   // ...
   double x = foos[some_idx].get_data_at_timepoint(some_timepoint);
   // ...
};
```

The `Library #2` I want to also have is `Library #1` at a **single point in time**. Something like:

```
class Foo2 {
private:
    double data;

public:
    double get_data() const;

    // All those other methods of Foo
}

class Bar2 {
private:
    std::vector<Foo2> foos;

public:
    Foo2 get_this_foo_2(int idx) const;
    void do_something();
    // All those other methods of Bar
}
```

where now:

```
void Bar2::do_something() {
   // ...
   double x = foos[some_idx].get_data();
   // ...
};
```

Clearly, `Foo2` is basically just `Foo`, but with a single data entry. I could rewrite all of `Foo`, but then I would have to duplicate all the methods. I want instead to define a thin wrapper of `Foo` that is of length 1 (a single datapoint).

For `Foo2`, there are two options: (1) subclass `Foo`, or (2) have `Foo2` be a wrapper around a unique ptr to `Foo`. I think (2) is better because the user should not have access to e.g. timepoints in base class `Foo`.

I also want to avoid writing extra code for `Bar`. The function `do_something` of course needs to be adapted slightly in `Bar2`, but overall these two seem so parallel. A lot of the other methods in `Bar` are also the same.

How do I avoid code duplication for `Foo2` and `Bar2`?

Comment: Inherit from `Bar` and hide `do_something` with a new method that does what you want.

Comment: But then `get_this_foo_2` would actually return a `Foo` object instead of a `Foo2`, correct?

Comment: You can make a BarBase template class with all the methods currently in Bar, but add an abstract get_data_from_foo member function. Make Bar inherit from BarBase<Foo> and Bar2 from BarBase<Foo2>. All you have to do in each is implement get_data_from_foo using the corresponding method.

Comment: That is the reason why in many c++ libraries the classes itself have only a small amount of member functions, that are limited to what is really needed to describe the type. Every thing else is solved using free functions, this allows you to modular the the code and to reuse functionality in an better way. So use only member functions to hide the implementation details of the data structure of the class or if virtual is needed, for everything else you most of the time want to use free functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
template <typename FooType>
class BarBase {
private:
    std::vector<FooType> foos;
protected:
    virtual double get_data_from_foo(unsigned int, void*) = 0;
public:
    void do_something();
    // all other methods that used to be in Bar
};

class Bar : public BarBase<Foo> {
protected:
    virtual void get_data_from_foo(unsigned int id, void* time_ptr) {
        return foos[id].get_data_at_timepoint(*(timepoint_t*)time_ptr);
    }
};

class Bar2 : public BarBase<Foo2> {
protected:
    virtual void get_data_from_foo(unsigned int id, void* dummy) {
        return foos[id].get_data();
    }
};
```

You’ll have to call get_data_from_foo() inside BarBase::do_something(). You also have to calculate the time point and pass it to that function, regardless of whether it’s needed.

Alternatively, if you don’t mind the code duplication inside do_something(), remove get_data_from_foo() and add a do_something() member function to each of Bar and Bar2, defining them separately.

Comment: this is awesome, `c++` is awesome, everything is awesome. thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is the reason why in many c++ libraries the classes itself have only a small amount of member functions, that are limited to what is really needed to describe the type. Every thing else is solved using free functions, this allows you to modular the the code and to reuse functionality in an better way.

So use only member functions to hide the implementation details of the data structure of the class or if virtual is needed, for everything else you most of the time want to use free functions.

An implementation might look something like that (that's just a proof of concept code to illustrate that usage of free functions):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
private: 
   std::vector<double> data = {1,2,3};
public:
   std::vector<double>::const_iterator begin() const {
      return data.begin();
   }

   std::vector<double>::const_iterator end() const {
      return data.end();
   }

   double first() const {
     return *begin();
   }
};

class Foo2 {
private: 
   double data = 42;

public:
   const double * begin() const {
      return &data;
   }

    const double * end() const {
      return &data + 1;
   }

   double first() const {
     return *begin();
   }
};

template<typename T>
double get_data_at_timepoint(const T &obj, size_t index) {
    auto it = obj.begin()+index;
    return *it;
}

template<typename T>
double get_data(const T &obj) {
    return obj.first();
}


int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Foo2 f2;

    double d = get_data_at_timepoint(f, 2);
    double d2 = get_data_at_timepoint(f2, 0);


    double d3 = get_data(f);
    double d4 = get_data(f2);
   // double d2 = get_data_at_timepoint(f2, 0);
    std::cout << "get_data_at_timepoint " << d << " " << d2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "get_data " << d3 << " " << d4 << std::endl;
}
```

Now you can use your `get_data_at_timepoint` with any data type that supports an iterator with the type `double` and it is not limited to you class `Foo` at all.

If `get_data_at_timepoint` is special for one of those classes you could created a specialized version for just that class:

```
template<>
double get_data_at_timepoint<Foo>(const Foo &obj, size_t index) {
    // Foo related implementation
}
```